# php-fpm 5.4 cannot start, just get a "failed" message

Tags: php

When i try to start php-fpm (v5.4.12) i just get a "failed" message.
No logs, no more info than that.

My machine uses debian 6 (squeeze) and compiled php just fine, everything went without an error, i'm just having this problem with php-fpm.

The weirdest thing is that i can't get any info about the error D:

Obviously the first thing i tried to do was to check the logs, but no logs are created... even more weird D:!

Here's my php-fpm.conf file:

```
[global]

pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /www/logs/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice
emergency_restart_threshold = 0
emergency_restart_interval = 0
process_control_timeout = 0
daemonize = yes

;  pools defined in virtual hosts
include=/home/vhosts/*/conf/php-fpm.include
Then each host has its own config in php-fpm.include as follows.

[main]

listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen.backlog = -1
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

; Unix user/group of processes
user = <not-showing-my-user-on-purpose>
group = <not-showing-my-user-on-purpose>

; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 100

; Pass environment variables
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

Comment: Starting php-fpm: [10-May-2013 00:09:08] ERROR: failed to daemonize: Cannot allocate memory (12)
[10-May-2013 00:09:08] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
                                                           [FAILED]  This is what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try running php-fpm with a "-n" option. If it succeeds, try disabling modules one by one until you find the broken one.

In my case (php-fpm 5.5 RC) it was gd's fault.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue after installing php from source and copying over the php-fpm init.d file, i had to edit /etc/init.d/php-fpm and change the location of the pid file to remove the prefix and then it restarted perfectly.

changed from this:

```
php_fpm_PID=${prefix}/var/run/php-fpm.pid
```

to this, which matches my php-fpm.conf file pid location:

```
php_fpm_PID=/var/run/php-fpm.pid
```